# After Spring boot 3, Hibernate 6 Migration - 'IN' clause in subquery no longer working for H2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, java-17, hibernate-6.x

Recently I have migrated a project to Spring Boot 3 and Java 17.
And it seems that there are a lot of bugs with the new Hibernate 6 version?

The issue I have encountered and debugged to death is that in our tests running on H2 the IN clauses are not translated correctly.
We have a query that is dynamically built in the following format:
`DELETE FROM LqTable WHERE (calcId,Nr) IN (SELECT calc.calcId,lpqv2.Nr FROM LqTable lpqv2 JOIN CalcTable calc ON calc.calcId=lpqv2.calcId WHERE (calc.pId, lpqv2.Nr) IN ((?1,?2),(?3,?4)))`

When executed (The query is executed using JPA's entity manager) we get the this error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM LqTable WHERE (calcId,Nr) IN (SELECT (calc.calcId,lpqv2.Nr) FROM LqTable lpqv2 JOIN CalcTable calc ON calc.calcId=lpqv2.calcId WHERE (calc.pId=? and lpqv2.Nr) or 
(calc.pId=? and lpqv2.Nr))
[21002-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:188)
    at org.h2.value.ValueRow.compareTypeSafe(ValueRow.java:119)
    at org.h2.value.Value.compareToNotNullable(Value.java:2634)
    at org.h2.value.Value.compareTo(Value.java:2607)
    at org.h2.value.ValueRow.compareTypeSafe(ValueRow.java:124)
    at org.h2.value.Value.compareToNotNullable(Value.java:2634)
    at org.h2.value.Value.compareTo(Value.java:2607)
    at org.h2.value.CompareMode.compare(CompareMode.java:280)
    at org.h2.value.CompareMode.compare(CompareMode.java:20)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:344)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:279)
    at org.h2.result.LocalResult.containsDistinct(LocalResult.java:249)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionInQuery.getValue(ConditionInQuery.java:95)
    at org.h2.expression.condition.ConditionInQuery.getValue(ConditionInQuery.java:55)
    at org.h2.expression.Expression.getBooleanValue(Expression.java:332)
    at org.h2.command.dml.FilteredDataChangeStatement.nextRow(FilteredDataChangeStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:58)
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:74)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.StandardJdbcMutationExecutor.execute(StandardJdbcMutationExecutor.java:84)
    ... 204 common frames omitted
```

From what I can tell it seems that the H2Dialect translation process is faulty:
`DELETE FROM LqTable WHERE (calcId,Nr) IN (SELECT (calc.calcId,lpqv2.Nr) FROM LqTable lpqv2 JOIN CalcTable calc ON calc.calcId=lpqv2.calcId WHERE (calc.pId=? and lpqv2.Nr) or  (calc.pId=? and lpqv2.Nr))`

The issue here, besides that it changes the IN clause, is that the syntax at the start of the subquery is incorrect `(SELECT **(**calc.calcId,lpqv2.Nr**)** FROM LqTable`, the parenthesis should not be there.

I have tried every version of Hibernate 6 from 6.0.0 to 6.1.7, and all spring boot versions from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 just to be sure, but nothing changed.
I have also tried to execute this as a native query but the sql that ends up being executed is somehow even more messed up.

I have debugged the hibernate code and what I have come up with is that the reason for this mess-up is that when translating the query hibernate checks if there is support for In clauses in subqueries by checking the version of the H2Dialect but this comes up with version 0.0.0. (This is checked in AbstractSqlAstTranslator at line 4281 that basically calls the H2SqlAstTranslator.supportsRowValueConstructorSyntaxInInList which checks that the version is newer than 1.4.197 from what I can tell).

From what I can tell this appears to be a bug?
Has anyone encountered anything like this? Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your are using H2 DB for tests, is aplication is also working with H2 DB or your using anyother DB? if your using other DB then is this SQL working?

Comment: Yes, we are using H2 for testing. Sorry if I wasn't clear. The query runs fine on our production db (We are running on Hana if it matters). Checked what query ends up being executed and it is parsed correctly.

Comment: The it's issue with H2 not Hibernate. we had same issue and did following changes to use h2 with legacy mode which uses legacy functions from H2 DB. spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY; and try with  <h2.version>2.1.210</h2.version>

Comment: We are already using the Legacy mode, tried removing it, but it has no effect. We are using version 2.1.214. I do not think the issue comes from the H2 package, as we have not changed that and it worked before. The problem appeared after we updated Hibernate to a version greater than 6. Also, the H2Dialect class that does the query parsing/translation is part of Hibernate.

Comment: This is not an issue with H2, the generated query is obliviously incorrect and will not work in any compatibility mode. (Actually it is a query for very old unsupported versions of H2 Database, they didn't have row values, it shouldn't be generated for H2 2.1.214.)

Comment: My best guess is that the issue comes from the fact that the version for the H2Dialect object is not setup correctly somehow. But I can't tell if it is because I am missing something, or it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in version `6.2.4`, at least temporarily. (The default constructor of H2Dialect starts with version `1.4.197` instead of `0.0.0`, also `supportsRowValueConstructorSyntaxInInList` defaults to true).

But for us this version introduces new unsolved issue... So if anyone encounters this same issue or something similar, I have found the following set of properties that provide a workaround to the invalid version:

```
jakarta.persistence.database-product-name = H2
jakarta.persistence.database-major-version = 2
jakarta.persistence.database-minor-version = 1
```

Note this is just for the test configuration.

EDIT: This also seems to be caused by `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false`